# How to go back to home page in wordpress project?

Tags: wordpress

Here, when i click Go Back button it perfectly goes to back page

```
<script>
function goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
</script>
<div class="back">
<button onclick="goBack()" class="btn btn-voilet" > << Go Back</button>
</div>
```

Now if i click back to curriculum button, it doesnt go back to home page can someone help me do it,

```
<script>
function back_to_curriculum() {
    window.history.home();
}
</script>
<div class="home">

<button onclick="back_to_curriculum()" class="btn btn-voilet" > << Back to Curriculum</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of Wordpress' `home_url()` function to get the Home URL of the site, then use Javascript to navigate there:

```
<script>
    function back_to_curriculum() {
        window.location.href = '<?php echo home_url(); ?>';
    }
</script>
```